# Android Studio 4.0.1 unable to locate adb

Tags: android, adb

I have been getting (unable to locate adb) on my android.
**So far, I've tried:**

- copying the adb.exe from a new download.
- Adding adb path to env.
- Changing GPU to software and hardware as well.
- Uninstalling then reinstall.
- Uninstall sdk tools and reinstall.

**My machine is:**

- Win 10 Pro
- 2 X Xeon 5460 3.16
- 32GB Ram
- 3 SSDs ( total of 3TB ) ( they are all almost empty. )
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970

**Please any advise would be appreciated.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that my processor is pretty old and outdated, and thats mainly the reason for it.